# How to make heading take up all vertical space, pushing list to the right?

Tags: html, css

How can the following HTML:

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>

<h3>Category_1</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Subcat_1</li>
  <li>Subcat_2</li>
  <li>Subcat_3</li>
  <li>Subcat_4</li>
  <li>Subcat_5</li>
  <li>Subcat_6</li>
  <li>Subcat_7</li>
  <li>Subcat_8</li>
  <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category_2</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Subcat_1</li>
  <li>Subcat_2</li>
  <li>Subcat_3</li>
  <li>Subcat_4</li>
  <li>Subcat_5</li>
  <li>Subcat_6</li>
  <li>Subcat_7</li>
  <li>Subcat_8</li>
  <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category_3</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Subcat_1</li>
  <li>Subcat_2</li>
  <li>Subcat_3</li>
  <li>Subcat_4</li>
  <li>Subcat_5</li>
  <li>Subcat_6</li>
  <li>Subcat_7</li>
  <li>Subcat_8</li>
  <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>
```

be formatted into a layout like this:

```
Heading
=======================

Category_1 ・Subcat_1 ・Subcat_2 ・Subcat_3
           ・Subcat_4 ・Subcat_5 ・Subcat_6
           ・Subcat_7 ・Subcat_8 ・Subcat_9

Category_2 ・Subcat_1 ・Subcat_2 ・Subcat_3
           ・Subcat_4 ・Subcat_5 ・Subcat_6
           ・Subcat_7 ・Subcat_8 ・Subcat_9

Category_3 ・Subcat_1 ・Subcat_2 ・Subcat_3
           ・Subcat_4 ・Subcat_5 ・Subcat_6
           ・Subcat_7 ・Subcat_8 ・Subcat_9
```

Specifically, how can an `<h3>` such as "Category_1" be made to take up all of the vertical space so that the `<ul>` begins to the right of it?

Let's pretend we don't know how many `<li>` there will be (it's not a fixed number).

I can compartmentalize everything into `<div>` containers and style them with Flexbox, but I was wondering if anyone has a more elegant idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the html (otherwise, @BimalPariyars [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387966/1168892) seems more elegant) but know how many categories you have, you can use a [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to accomplish your result. You basically create areas for the `h3`s and the `ul`s and assign them accordingly:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 100 %;
  grid-template-columns: auto repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "h2 h2"
    "h3_1 ul_1"
    "h3_2 ul_2"
    "h3_3 ul_3";
}

h2 { grid-area: h2; }

h3:nth-of-type(1) { grid-area: h3_1; }
h3:nth-of-type(2) { grid-area: h3_2; }
h3:nth-of-type(3) { grid-area: h3_3; }

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}
ul:nth-of-type(1) { grid-area: ul_1; }
ul:nth-of-type(2) { grid-area: ul_2; }
ul:nth-of-type(3) { grid-area: ul_3; }

li {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>

<h3>Category_1</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category_2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category_3</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Since your solution does not require modifying the HTML, I am selecting it as the best answer. I also appreciate your honest opinion that Bimal Pariyar's is more elegant if the the HTML can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menus {
    display: flex;
}

.menus ul{
    display: table;
}
.menus ul li{
   display: inline-flex;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>
<div class="menus">
<h3>Category_1</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="menus">
<h3>Category_2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="menus">
<h3>Category_3</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
    <li>Subcat_1</li>
    <li>Subcat_2</li>
    <li>Subcat_3</li>
    <li>Subcat_4</li>
    <li>Subcat_5</li>
    <li>Subcat_6</li>
    <li>Subcat_7</li>
    <li>Subcat_8</li>
    <li>Subcat_9</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="category-wrapper">

  <div class="category-1">Category</div>
  <div class="list-1-3">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-4-6">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-7-9">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="break">
  </div>
  <div class="category-2">Category</div>
  <div class="list-1-3">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-4-6">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-7-9">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="break">
  </div>
  <div class="category-3">Category</div>
  <div class="list-1-3">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-4-6">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-7-9">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="break">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.category-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/hjgqxe0r/